# LEFT JOIN returns everything with NULL

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables whome I am joining through left join. Both the tables are empty. But when I run the query, mysql returns a row with all NULLS.

I have tried several queries like

```
SELECT products.*,SUM(pq_quantity) as quantity
FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `products_quantities` ON `pq_product_idFk` = `p_id` 
WHERE `p_volusion_id` = '37808'
```

OR

```
SELECT products.*,SUM(pq_quantity) as quantity
FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `products_quantities` ON `pq_product_idFk` = `p_id` 
WHERE `p_volusion_id` = '37808' AND p_id IS NOT NULL
```

OR

```
SELECT products.*,SUM(pq_quantity) as quantity
FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `products_quantities` ON `pq_product_idFk` = `p_id` AND `p_volusion_id` = '37808' AND p_id IS NOT NULL
```

NONE of the above queries seem to work as I just want the result that is not NULL.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Why do I GROUP BY?

Comment: Try appending `GROUP BY p_id`

Comment: Yes I did that when you commented and it worked. What does it have to do with Group By?

Comment: Well `SUM` is an aggregate function and you have to create groups, so that a sum can be calculated for each one. In your case i guess you want one sum for each product.

Comment: The presence of [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) in the `SELECT` clause asks for the presence of the `GROUP BY` clause. However, if it is not present, a single group is created using all the rows filtered by the `WHERE` clause. Either way, the presence of `*` in the `SELECT` clause makes your query invalid SQL. It kindof works in MySQL but only before version 5.7.5. The values it returns for the columns that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause are [indeterminate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Both the tables are empty. But when I run the query, mysql returns a row with all `NULLS`.

The presence of [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) in the `SELECT` clause asks the `GROUP BY` clause to be present too. However, if it is not present, the SQL standard specifies that a single group is to be created using all the rows filtered by the `WHERE` clause.

Because of the `*` used in the `SELECT` clause, all the queries you posted are invalid SQL.

A query that contains a `GROUP BY` clause does not return rows from tables. It creates rows using the values extracted from the tables. First it creates groups (and sub-groups) using the expressions from the `GROUP BY` clause. All the rows from a group have the same value for the first expression specified in the `GROUP BY` clause.

If there are two or more expressions in the `GROUP BY` clause, each group is split into sub-groups using the second expression then each sub-group is further split into sub-sub-groups using the third expression (if exists) and so on.

From each such group of rows (after the last split), the database engine **generates** one new row and puts it into the result set. If the query contains in the `SELECT` clause expressions that are not either arguments of a `GRUP BY` aggregate function or also present in the `GROUP BY` clause then, most probably, these expressions will have more than one value in a subgroup. This is why the query is invalid SQL. Up to version 5.7.5, MySQL accepts such invalid queries but reserves itself the right to return [any value it wants](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) (from the group) for the offending expressions.

Back to your question, as explained above, even without having a `GROUP BY` clause, your query is processed as it had one and one group is created from all the rows filtered by the `WHERE` clause.

It is an empty group but this doesn't prevent the database engine to generate a row from it. Since there are no values to use to compute `SUM(pG_quantity)`, `NULL` is the logical value it returns in the columns of the result set.

`NULL` is a special value that means the absence of any value or an unknown value. It make perfect sense in your case. You don't have any value in the tables, there is no way one could compute `SUM(pq_quantity)`. Its value is not available (i.e. `NULL`).